# "[Error] expected expression before 'criatura'" em função

Tags: c

O tabuleiro é uma "criatura" do meu struct:

```
typedef struct{
    int status;
    char classe;
    int saude;
    int def;
    int atc;
    char elixir;
}criatura;
```

No .h:

```
void exibe(criatura tabuleiro[5][10]); // exibe o tabuleiro
```

A chamada no .c com as funções:

```
criatura tabuleiro[5][10]; // declarei aqui
// entraram alguns códigos aqui
exibe(criatura tabuleiro); // chamei a função aqui
```

A função:

```
void exibe(criatura tabuleiro[5][10]){
    int i,j;

    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        if(i==0){
            printf("     1");
        }
        if(i==1){
            printf("   2");
        } ............................. (apenas um tabuleiro)
```

Mas por algum motivo recebo o erro:

```
In function 'tabuleiro':
[Error] expected expression before 'criatura'
C:\Users\...\dfv2\Makefile.win  recipe for target 'funcoes.o' failed
```

Se alguém souber o que está dando errado, agradeço!
Um abraço!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A chamada da função está errado.

Você fez:

```
exibe(criatura tabuleiro);
```

Deveria ter feito:

```
exibe(tabuleiro);
```

O C já sabe que é criatura. No caso, você confundiu o compilador passando para ele um tipo e um nome. E essa estrutura não é válido quando se chama uma função. No caso, a gramática C pede que uma chamada seja constituída por:

1. Nome da função
2. Abre parêntese
3. Valores intercalados por vírgulas
4. Fecha parêntese

Tem algumas variações (C aceita ponteiros de função), mas em geral é isso.

Também vale dizer que para o `header` é necessário  conhecer o tipo `criatura` antes de declarar a função.